# How are negative exponents handeled in set theory?

Tags: set-theory

I understand that, in the context of set theory, we describe 2$^{1}$ as the set of all possible functions *f*: 1 $\rightarrow$ 2 with the cardinality of said set being the exponent's value. I am confused how this definition could be extended into statements such as 2$^{-1}$, given that in a set theoretic context -1 refers to an equivalence class. Thanks for any help

Comment: You're trying to mix arithmetic and set theoretic notations in a way that they really aren't designed to do. Not everything carries over nicely.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining

Comment: If you can define what is the meaning of 2^n/2^m with m<n. Or 2^n (2^m) then you can define it for 2^-1.

Comment: Simple answer: They aren't.

Comment: Simpler question, what is $\frac12^2$, then? And if $x+y$ is the cardinal addition what's $\frac12+\frac12$?

Comment: Related MO question: [Has negative cardinality been considered?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136366/has-negative-cardinality-been-considered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, $^12$ is the set of all functions $f:1\longrightarrow 2$, and its relation with the arithmetical $2^1$ is that $|^12|=2^1$. If you wanted to extend such property to negative exponents, you would need sets with "rational cardinality", which doesn't make any sense. For example: it would be senseless to talk about sets that have cardinality $\frac{1}{2}$